# Android doInBackground stops

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, adb

I've got a network between two android devices, one device will just send a position for a block to be, and then client connected to the phone will use those positions to show the block, the host can move the block and the client can see this, but after a random amount of time, the connection just drops, but I'm not sure if it is the connection or just the doInBackground method.

Here is the method that is causing me problems

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)
{
    setUpClient();
    if( host == true ) { server.execute(); }
    rdyForPlay = true;
    boolean run = true;
    while( run )
    {
        //Tell the server to give position of players
        if( host == false)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Running client doInBackgroundMethod");
            try {
                if(socket == null)
                {
                    socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
                }
                byte[] bufer = new byte[256];
                String msg = "position";
                int msgLength = msg.length();
                bufer = msg.getBytes();
                InetAddress address;
                address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.59");
                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( bufer, bufer.length , address, port );
                socket.send( p );

            } catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
            try 
            {
                socket.receive( packet );
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );
            Log.d(TAG, "Data received is in run method:" + data);
            //Take the data from the server and use it
            String[] pos = data.split(":");
            assets.get(0).setPosition( Integer.parseInt( pos[0] ), Integer.parseInt( pos[1] ) );
            //ID = Integer.parseInt( data );
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

More code can be given if needed.

Canvas

Comment: in which case run can become 'false'?

Comment: the value of run is never false, just got it to send a total of 23k packets, then the client just stopped spamming "Running client doInBackgroundMethod", i have changed the code to output an error code if it does a catch, but still nothing.

Comment: This pattern isn't a good fit for an `AsyncTask`. Look into using a `Thread` and communicate with the UI through a `Handler`. An `AsyncTask` is for, well... "tasks", not for indefinite runs.

Comment: Well, I tried to create my doInBackground as a run method, but my draw method wasn't being ran, and that is also with a thread. so kinda confused :)

Comment: Ok i just changed all AsyncTask methods to run and it works fine, I will do more testing on the connect issue later :),